# What is CHECKSUM in CREATE TABLE statement and what is default value?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, teradata

I could see `CHECKSUM = DEFAULT` is always defined in CREATE STATEMENT table.
could any one please tell me What is CHECKSUM in CREATE TABLE statement and what is **DEFAULT** value ?

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.MyTable ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
```

Note: The above structure is taken from Teradata table structure but you can answer me in terms of any Database.

Comment: _Set this to 1 if you want MySQL to maintain a live checksum for all rows (that is, a checksum that MySQL updates automatically as the table changes). This makes the table a little slower to update, but also makes it easier to find corrupted tables. The CHECKSUM TABLE statement reports the checksum. (MyISAM only.)_ source: [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `DEFAULT` uses systemwide global value which can be defined using DBS Control utility.

This is applicable to Teradata databases, since checksum integrity is implemented differently for different databases (so it's not possible to answer this in terms of 'any database'), though some may look similar. For more on Teradata `CHECKSUM` [see documentation](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1094_111A/ch12.053.77.html).

As for the `CHECKSUM` purpose, it's an additional (to file system) data integrity verification. The hash is calculated over data being written, and is written alongside it. On subsequent read hash is calculated from read data, and compared. If they differ, this means that data was corrupted.

Comment: thanks. But still the document does not explain what is checksum and what is the use of it ?. Only default values are explained. Could u  pls explain ?